# Suspending An Object in Time

Tags: science-based, physics, time

I am curious about the real world physics of an object suspended in time for a short time. In video games like *Legend of Zelda* there is an ability the player can use which freezes an object in time. The player is then able to hit the object, which the game calls storing kinetic energy. When the object unfreezes it launches away according to that stored kinetic energy.
Here is an example I found on YouTube:https://youtu.be/7Ekbx_tSfS4

Is this how a "timeless" object would actually react? My limited understanding would say no as the object is not subject to the passing of time at all. However, I could be wrong.

In a reverse situation, what about objects already in motion? Let's say a cannon ball is fired, you freeze the cannon ball alone. The gas from the black powder continues on as normal and then you unfreeze the cannon ball, would it also continue on as normal? Would the cannon ball "save it's kinetic energy" per se?

Comment: As far as I know, nobody managed to freeze an object in time nor see a frozen one, even less on a well-defined object and even less and less unfreezing it afterwards. By lack of observation, this also applies to any scientific hypothesis made around it. This most likely means that you could go in most directions you want, and few will actually be able to complain about it :).

Comment: @Tortliena you could make observations about a weird space-time curve where one object is inside a simulated gravity well (which for convenience sake does not destroy it) and another on a flat space-time curve on a collision course. The gravity well would be exactly as large as the object and have virtually no curve outside it (so basically a weird black hole is inside the object). Then say stuff about how they interact.

Comment: If you were to freeze a cannonball (and it is still inside the barrel), the gas continuing as normal would be the barrel blowing apart as you suddenly create a giant stopper inside of it. Whether a moving object continues after being 'time'-stopped and unfrozen is up to you, as we simply don't know yet.

Comment: According to physics as we know it, you can't "stop" something in time. It would necessarily involve making it non-interactable with any other forces. That is the only way to really have it unaffected by time. If there is no forces at work and no processes/reactions then for all intents and purposes time doesn't exist. There is no reference point to measure time. There is nothing happening. The question cannot really be answered based on science as the premise is non-scientific.

Comment: @Demigan That wouldn't be "stopping" time in its strict meaning, as gravity wells don't stop time "to exactly 0%". Let's not forget that you add a premise which ultimately and directly alters the answer ("*assuming it does not get destroyed*")

Comment: I'm voting to close because the current definition of the wanted time-stop is unclear, at the very least for a science-based question : Whether it's a true stop or a "feels like it has stopped", if it is a field or not, etc...

Comment: @Tortliena then closed it shall be. I feel I should apologize because based on these answers I didn't do a great job explaining my question. I'm a fantasy writer more than a science-fiction writer and was just curious about a more "realistic" take on freezing an object in time. Thanks for the answers however! They give me enough to think about and if it comes to it, I can always fall back on "it's fantasy, dude." ;)

Comment: @Tortliena I’d assume a technomagical time stop and obviously the object isnt destroyed as thats not what is interesting for the question and outside its scope. You can determine what happens to a slower-in-time object interaction versus a faster-in-time one, then extrapolate that difference to infinity and presto, an answer! For a real-world equivalent: assume two particles around a micro black hole hit one another, with one coming from “above”. The time difference is small but still relevant.

Comment: @Demigan You should know that at the center of a black hole happens a singularity, it's a bit like dividing by zero : It doesn't end with infinity nor -infinity, and that's why at best we can tell that we just don't know. But back to the question, yes the querent do ask what happens to an object when it is frozen, so it **is essential when you predefine yourself that the object isn't destroyed**. It's far from being what our closest approximation of science tells, the most reasonable one without having one from the querent. Don't make too wild assumptions.

Comment: @PeanutNutter You don't need to tell what happens to the object, just how you see this time-stop so you don't (implicitly) ask us to create the timestop base mechanism on top of its actions. For instance, Zelda's timestop is atomic (only the object is affected), but it could be a field like [Braid's "ring of slow"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWGCqfa3lcE&t=4400s). And you have first to choose whether it's this or Zelda ^^. Last note : If you want to look more sciency, black holes and relativistic travels might be interesting to look into, they're the typical hard-science looking stuff ^^.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting this in my "to close" queue when it's already closed. The answer to this question would be intrinsically tied to the time stopping mechanism. In my world, I actually have two separate time-slowing mechanisms, and they would behave differently. I would suggest looking into Niven's "Slaver stasis fields"

Answer (score 4):

## Problems and weirdness with stopping time

Time is very elusive. Imagine firing a cannonball and taking single 'frozen' moments in time of it. Each time you look at the ball you notice something important. The ball isn't moving. In each frame it is impossible to know which way it is moving in both absolute terms and relative terms. Only when time is 'moving', the universe is moving.

To get back to your original question, what would happen if you froze time? It is currently impossible to know. Thus it depends on what you want. Here are some ideas:

If time isn't moving for an object, there is no interaction possible. Hitting it with a baseball bat would not impart any energy into the object, as the object is unable to receive it. The problem is that any interaction is impossible, as time is frozen. So any molecular force that keeps things 'solid', or pushes back or whatever do not work. The bat can't bounce off the object, as that requires interaction. It'll pass right through without hitting it. Molecules are > 99% empty space. Even if two molecules hit each other, there still can't be any interaction. It'll just go straight through without interaction.

If time is frozen, it can't be altered. That means the object is certainly there, but nothing can enter or leave that frozen time sphere. If you try to have anything enter or leave that space, you'll again have no interaction. It isn't the molecules you interact with, but the frozen area of time. How that interacts is up to you, but it might just as well be an indestructible block of stone.

If time is frozen it still accepts interactions. Like in the intro, a cannonball looks frozen from moment to moment in time, but the important thing is that despite this travel consisting of an infinite frozen moments, it still interacts with everything regardless. It was fired and is slowing down due to wind resistance, or slow down more in the upcomming soldiers. That means hitting this cannonball from the side it's flying towards  with a bat will absolutely shatter the bat, as the energy of the ball is still present and will be pushed into the bat, but the ball will equally slow down.

### It's not really frozen

But considering what happens in the gane we can say it's something completely different. We know from earlier games that they do travel through space on a planet (despite the weird moon thing). Assuming it's relative to Earth (it's not, but let's simplify), we see a big problem arising immediately. The Earth is moving 1600 kilometers per hour in its rotation on the equators, *as well as* 107000 kilometers per hour around the sun. The sun is moving around in a galaxy at high speeds, which moves through a galactic cluster, which is moving an undetermined amount of speed through the emptiness of space.

Unless there is a huge prank on all of us and due to some weirdness the Earth is perfectly stationary in the universe, you'll lose your frozen time item in less than the blink of an eye. It'll fly off into the Earth or sky, not interacting as it phases through, or not interacting as it leaves a hole in the sky or Earth [and some fusion explosion due to the friction](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/), or does the former *and* shoot off at the highest speed in the universe right after the time freeze ends. Either one of these, or items in Zelda aren't actually frozen in time. Something else happens and you can store energy as it floats in it's weird stasis. In short, it does what a writer wants it to do.